# getJSON not working for second function

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code:

```
function place(a, text) {
'use strict';
a.html(text);
}

(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.surah = function (sura, aya) {
        var x = aya,
            getAR = $.getJSON("js/quran/" + sura + ".json");

        getAR.done(function (data_ar) {
            place($(this), data_ar[x - 1].text);
        });
    };

    $.fn.trans = function (sura, aya) {
        var y = xy[sura] < 1559 ? 1 : (xy[sura] < 1559 * 2 ? 2 : (xy[sura][0] < 1559 * 3 ? 3 : 4)),
            x = xy[sura][0] + aya,
            getEN = $.getJSON("js/quran_en/" + y + ".json");

        getEN.done(function (data_en) {
            console.log(data_en[x]);
            place($(this), data_en[x].text);
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

which accesses 2 json files depending on which of the 2 jquery functions you use.

The first one (`getAR`) works as I want it to, however the second one won't seem to actually get the JSON data.

Comment: what is xy  in xy[sura]??

Comment: It's an array with info on the surahs...
`xy[surah number][0]` should return the sum of the ayah numbers up to `surah number`.

`xy[2][4]` should return 7+4 = 11

Comment: ok try to set  y  and  x manually with specific values and see your function will work or not

Comment: Check whether you get any errors in console

Comment: everything after getEN.done() doesn't work.